SaveAsFile method with two parameters throwing an error
While working with Selenium in C#, I encountered an issue when trying to use the SaveAsFile method with two parameters. Specifically, I wanted to pass ScreenshotImageFormat.png" as the second parameter, but I kept getting a compile-time error.
Code snippet throwing the error:
 screenshot.SaveAsFile(screenshotLocation, ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);

My whole method:
public string addScreenshot(IWebDriver driver, ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
{
    ITakesScreenshot takesScreenshot = (ITakesScreenshot)driver;

    Screenshot screenshot = takesScreenshot.GetScreenshot();
    string screenshotLocation = Path.Combine(testResultPath, scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Title + ".Jpeg");

    // this line is causing compile time error.
    screenshot.SaveAsFile(screenshotLocation, ScreenshotImageFormat.Jpeg);

    // this is working fine
    screenshot.SaveAsFile("manas.png");

    return screenshotLocation;
}


What is your compile error? The obvious question here is does this method take two parameters and if it does what is the signature of the method in that case?

What library are you using?
Because OpenQA.Selenium.Screenshot object doesn't contain an overload method SaveAsFile with second parameter. Only this signature is enabled:
public override void SaveAsFile(string fileName)
{
    File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, base.AsByteArray);
}

So you should use your second approach:
// this is working fine
screenshot.SaveAsFile("manas.png");

Note:
Also, in the tooltip of SaveAsFile() it states, "Saves the screenshot to a Portable Network Graphics (PNG) file, overwriting the file if it already exists." so there is no option to choose an output format.

Also, in the tooltip of SaveAsFile() it states, "Saves the screenshot to a Portable Network Graphics (PNG) file, overwriting the file if it already exists." so there is no option to choose an output format.

@JeffC You are right. I updated my answer. If someone have a problem with output format they know what to do  ;)
